# pfsense multi wan + vlans = отваливаются vlan'ы

Tags: маршрутизация

Есть два провайдера. Один на pppoe а другой на ipoe.
Есть 6 подсетей которые подключены к procurve 2824 (layer-2).
Собственно создаю gateway group и в firewall->rules задаю правило интерфейсу wired_lan (он же vlan 100):

> proto: ipv4
>   source: wired_lan_net
>   port: *
>   destination: *
>   port: *
>   gateway: loadbalance

После чего в wired_lan пропадает доступ к другим vlan (110,200,400,500,600) ну и другие vlan'ы тоже не видят друг друга.
Firewall->nat->outbound по умолчанию стоит интерфейс первого провайдера (pppoe).
Куда копать?

Comment: Дополните свой вопрос типом оборудования которое вы настраиваете. Так больше шансов, что на вопрос ответят

Comment: @tutankhamun Обычный писюк с тремя сетевыми интерфейсами (два ван и один лан).

Comment: И еще сопутствующий вопрос: если коммутатор работает в режиме layer-2 то intervlan'а же не должно быть? В vlan110 включен порт 12 untagged которого нету в vlan100. Pfsense подключен к порту 1 который присутствует в тегированном виде в vlan100 и vlan110 но почему то пинги идут с vlan100 на vlan110 (имею ввиду машины в vlan'ах а не их интерфейсы) и обратно чего по моему не должно быть или все таки маршрутизатор разруливает по доброте душевной?